# Does a package created to be used for other programs need to be compiled?

Tags: java

In Java, when create a package to be used by other programs, does the package need to be compiled?

In other words, when we talk about using a package,

- is the package necessarily in bytecode and in either .class or .jar file?
- Or can it be in Java language and in .java file?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'package'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If compiled with the 'package', of course other programs can use plain `.java` files if they're included in the classpath when compiling (the same way it uses *your* files). The Java compiler would just compile the 'package' too and add it to the final result without distinction.

But when talking about a package or a library, only `.class` files (optionally in a `jar`) are allowed, that can be accessed and used by the [Java ClassLoader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader). The JVM wouldn't bother stopping to compile code while loading a library.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be compiled in order to be used by other programs. Java Virtual Machine (JVM) runs on [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode), which is the compiled `.class` file.

The fact that JVM uses the compiled form saves time during startup and also makes it possible to run programs in [JVM languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages) other than Java, if they share the same binary form (examples: Scala, Groovy, Clojure...). 
This way one JVM can run a single program, which was originally written in multiple of these languages. For example the program is in Scala, but the libraries were originally (before compilation) written in Java.